# How to run gcov on test application with Nuttx OS on STM discovery board?

Tags: gcc, arm, gcov, eabi

Setup:
Toolchain: gcc-arm-none-eabi-5_2-2015q4-20151219
Target: STM429i-disco board

I want to run gcov and get real time report generated in target as per below link:
https://mcuoneclipse.com/2014/12/26/code-coverage-for-embedded-target-with-eclipse-gcc-and-gcov/

First, sucessfully have compiled my code (POSIX compliant NUTTX OS) with -fprofile-arcs & -ftest-coverage flags & got generated the .gcno files for my src files.

second, sucesfully have linked with -fprofile-arcs flags enabled and using the libgcov.a file (part of the toolchain) and the final binary is generated.

Now, I dont know what changes are needed in my test application to invoke gcov, generate report & dump report.

Another problem is, gcov functions are with HIDDEN attribute in libgcov.a as below.
9: 00000000     4 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 __gcov_flush
9: 00000000     4 FUNC    GLOBAL HIDDEN     1 __gcov_init

so, I could not invoke as I need.

Any inputs in getting the .gcda file generated would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you look for `gcov_exit` instead? It is similar to `__gcov_flush`. Typically, it's one of `gcov_exit` and `__gcov_flush` that would be there and you can use any.

In case this is not there or is also hidden, you can use this approach which I tried for one of my projects. I picked (and modified for various reasons) the implementation of `gcov_exit` from gcc source code (of version matching my toolchain) (available at https://github.com/reeteshranjan/libgcov-embedded) and plugged it in my project. With everything else remaining the same (the compiler flags etc.), I was able to then break into `gcov_exit` and follow the rest of the approach in the blog link you have mentioned.